# c3p0 logs with Play Framework 1?

Tags: debugging, logging, log4j, playframework-1.x, c3p0

Is there a way to get c3p0 debug logs shown with Play framework 1.2.5?

Somebody had asked this at [Play email list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/o6dQymbq4hg/discussion); at least adding the following to log4j.properties does NOT work:

```
log4j.logger.com.mchange.v2.c3p0=DEBUG
log4j.category.com.mchange=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.mchange=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some Play source code reading, [DBPlugin:onApplicationStart](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org%24maven2@com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.playframework%24play@1.2.5@play%24db%24DBPlugin.java) seems to have the following:

```
...
System.setProperty("com.mchange.v2.log.MLog", "com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog");
System.setProperty("com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_LEVEL", "OFF");
ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
...
```

After commenting out these System.setProperty lines and building a local jar, I was able to see the c3p0 logging.

Don't know if there some way to enable logging other than this?

Comment: Oh. That's pretty bad. They've effectively turned off all c3p0 logging via system properties, and the highest priority means of configuring the logging library. That shouldn't be done in code, but apparently it is. You've done the right thing to undo it.

Answer (score 1):

do you see c3p0 logging information anywhere? is it coming through standard out, or through java.util.logging?

anyway, one thing to try is

```
com.mchange.v2.log.MLog=com.mchange.v2.log.log4j.Log4jMLog
```

you can put that in a c3p0.properties file, or set it as a System property (or create a file called mchange-log.properties). see [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_logging) for more.

Comment: Nothing shown at standard out or log4j logs. With some source crawling I found out a likely reason, I'll make another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in your application.conf file?

```
# Debug SQL statements (logged using DEBUG level):
jpa.debugSQL=true
```

Not sure if it will give you the logs you need, but worth a try.

Comment: Checking the source code, jpa.debugSQL=true ends up with `org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL").setLevel(Level.ALL);` when otherwise level is set to Level.OFF. So it will have effect on Hibernate SQL logging.

Answer (score 0):

On the discussion, avfl & Scott found out another way with OnApplicationStart job:

```
package jobs;

import play.jobs.*;
import play.Logger;

@OnApplicationStart
public class C3p0Logging extends Job {

    public void doJob() {
        Logger.info("Setting custom c3p0 log level");
        com.mchange.v2.log.log4j.Log4jMLog.getLogger().setLevel(com.mchange.v2.log.MLevel.FINEST);
    }   
}
```

This seems to end up to c3p0 FallbackMLog -> System.err. Haven't found a way to get the logs to log4j with this approach.